# Will the Rosetta Stone online edition work with Ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility

The [Rosetta Stone Online Edition](http://www.rosettastone.com/pe/v3/tot) claims that it requires:

```
Windows: XP SP3, Vista SP2, or Windows 7
Mac (Intel based only): Leopard, Snow Leopard, or Lion (OS X 10.5 or higher)
Internet Explorer 7, Firefox 3, Safari 3, Chrome 8 or greater
Adobe Flash Player version 10.1 or greater
```

Yet, I would guess if it works on Chrome and Firefox and only requires Flash versoin 10.1, it'd work on Ubuntu too... Can anyone confirm?

Please no speculating, only answer if you can confirm or deny it works.

Comment: Have you resolved this question?

Comment: @pl1nk no all I see speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the online demo is working. However the full version is not.

The full version will initially load and you can navigate but as soon as you select and start a lesson all you get is the background image and nothing more. I tried this with Chrome 22.0 and Firefox 16.0.2.

**Edit:**
I switched chrome to the beta channel (version 24.0.1312.40 beta) and now every thing is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

ive been using the full version for my school and it works fine on ubuntu 13.10 and whatever firefox that ships with, the only thing that doesn't work is the writing.  it just sits there with a blank screen and doesn't load. but everything else, along with the speaking, is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the online demo and it's working for me on Firefox 13.0

There should also be a money back guarantee policy.